# Changing Linked Table Source Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

I am trying to change the links in an Access 2016 database, but the method I've used in the past is not working as required.

I am using the

```
 t.connect="new connection"
 t.refreshlink
```

method, where t is a the table.

I have seen in the linked table manager that the tables are now grouped by a data source.  I can create the new source and link it to the desired table, but I have many as migrating, so would like to do this in code.

I get no errors the current way, but immediately after the `.refreshlink` the table's `.connect` is still the same.

Is this still possible?

I currently populate a dictionary with the table name and it's existing connection, but only if non ODBC.

I am then looping through this dictionary, getting the table and changing its connection

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect = strNewConnection
CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).RefreshLink
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect
```

Existing connection = `;DATABASE=\\app01\Access\CRM_Data.mdb` 
New connection =`;DATABASE=C:\CRM_TEST\CRM_DATA_BE_2016.accdb`

Many thanks

Comment: @ErikA I've added the code that I am trying, as much is relevant, if you need to see anything else let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `CurrentDb.TableDefs` when changing tables, as that changes between calls and makes the reference to the tabledef where you change the connection string be a different one than the one where you refresh the link.

```
Dim d As DAO.Database
Set d = CurrentDb
d.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect = strNewConnection
d.TableDefs(strTableName).RefreshLink
```

AFAIK this behaviour is not version-dependent, so the code you provided should never have worked.

Comment: Of course you need to do it for all your tables and when you add a new one you need to adjust the code. See my solution below: set it and forget it.

Comment: @Vlado Yeah, your "solution" contains exactly the same error and thus won't fix this problem at all...

Comment: Then the problem is in your connection string

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in Access 2016 and it works just fine:

```vb
Public Function RelinkTables(environment As Integer)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tblDef As DAO.TableDef

    For Each tblDef In CurrentDb.TableDefs    
        If tblDef.Connect <> "" Then
            tblDef.Connect = GetConnectionString(environment)
            tblDef.RefreshLink
        End If    
    Next

End Function

Public Function GetConnectionString(environment As Integer) As String
    Select Case environment
        Case 1 ' connection to Test db
            GetConnectionString = "your connection string to Test"
        Case 2  ' connection to Prod db
            GetConnectionString = "your connection string to Production"
    End Select
End Function
```

If this would not work with your db than may be the path is wrong.

Comment: thanks the `GetConnectionString` is returning "sub or function not defined" error??

Comment: This is my function which you replace with yours - returns the connection string you want to use. :-) Or just enter your connection string there. I guarantee it works - I am using that every day in my office - switching between Test and Production. You do not need to change your code when you create a new link. It works automatically.

Comment: I putted up there the function GetConnectionString